# How to rerender component on variable change which is imported from a helper script?

Tags: javascript, lit-element

I have something like the code below and I would like to check with you if there is a better way to do this. Basically I have a helper script which gets data from a third party API. I would like the components that import this helper script to rerender every time the API is called. The API is called multiple times.

I'm doing this right now:

MyClass script:

```
import { rerenderComponentList } from '../../../helpers/myscript';

export default class MyClass extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      item: {},
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.item = [];

    rerenderComponentList(this);
  }

  render() {
    const icon = Iconify.renderSVG(this.item.icon, {});

    return html` <div>Hello</div> `;
  }

  static get styles() {
    return styles;
  }
}
```

The `rerenderComponentList` imported function is used to send the current element object to the helper script.

Helper script:

```
const list = [];

export function rerenderComponentList(object) {
  list.push(object);
}

function rerenderComponent() {
  list.map((item) => item.requestUpdate());
}

function callbackIcons(loaded) {
  if (loaded.length) {
    rerenderComponent();
  }
}

//Function used to call API in app.js
export function loadIcons(icons) {
  API.myfunction(icons, callbackIcons);
}
```

The `rerenderComponent` function is used to call the `requestUpdate` on each element object.

Any better and nicer suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Can you please include that on the question at the bottom. I understand that you want to call `requestUpdate`, but is that the case? why are you creating `list = 0`to store components and to render them again?

Comment: `rerenderComponent ` is never called in your code... Please I would advise you to read a bit more on component `state` and why it's important because for your component to re-render, you need to make use of state.

Comment: Thanks @MosiaThabo this code works and rerenderComponent is called on the API callback. You are right, I have more of a React background and Properties in LitElement I'm not fluent in yet. 

The above code is a stripped out example of what I have. For all the components that need to update ( and rerender ) every time the API callback is run, I am pushing the component instance into the `list` by using `rerenderComponentList` called in each component constructor. This way I have all instances in the helper script, so during the callback, I loop through the instances and call `requestUpdate`

Comment: I know that this is a dirty work around, I would someone to guide me to implement a proper solution for this.

Comment: What I want to achieve is this:

Basically I have a helper script which gets data from a third party API. I would like the components that import this helper script to rerender every time the API is called

Comment: I'll have a loot at this, I'm just not by my pc to answer because you responded late! it all makes sense, and I can already see the right approach that is more appropriate for your scenario

Comment: Just to understand, you're saying that your API call retrieves some values as list and then each component(instance in this case) must update based on the respective data of that list returned from an api call is that right?

Comment: Exactly that! I'm sorry for not replying earlier, been a really long time since I posted here and I was expecting an email for a reply or comment but I didn't get. But it's OK, please share your solution when ever you can!

Answer (score 0):

This is where the new [`ReactiveController`](https://lit.dev/docs/api/controllers/) can help. This lets you hook in to the component lifecycle, so your API can tell the `LitElement` when it needs to render:

```
import { ReactiveController, ReactiveControllerHost } from 'lit';

export class MyController 
    implements ReactiveController {

    list = [];

    constructor(private host: ReactiveControllerHost) {
        host.addController(this);
    }

    private callbackIcons(loaded) {
        this.list = loaded;
        this.host.requestUpdate();
    }
    
    loadIcons(icons) {
        API.myfunction(icons, items => this.callbackIcons(items));
    }
}
```

Then in your element:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit';
import { customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';
import { MyController } from './my-controller.js';

@customElement('my-element')
class MyElement 
    extends LitElement {

    private myController = new MyController(this);

    render() {
        const icons = this.myController.list.map(i => Iconify.renderSVG(i)) ;
        return html`... ${icons} ...`;
    }
}
```